# Name of this buttonstyle and code

Tags: android

i just wanted to know the name of this buttonstyle and what code i need to implement this button into my application.
I already searched for some buttonstyles but I couldn´t figure out the name for this one.
[image: Buttons]

Comment: It's possible that it's actually not even a buttonstyle, it might be a layout with an ImageView + a button/clickable text

Answer (score 0):

This are not buttons this are tabs. Search for tabs. Also you can achieve this using third party library like sherlock. Please refer develoerandroid.com for same.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Tabs section of this blog post:
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/04/customizing-action-bar.html

```
<!-- style for the tabs -->
<style name="MyActionBarTabStyle" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBarView_TabView">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_tab_bg</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">32dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">32dp</item>
</style>
```